# MSSQL regex to detect if email starts with number.number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to exclude spam mails. Normally spam mails has 793.32.xxxx@gmail.com

How can i check in MSSQL if mail has this syntax. Somehow with regex?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "^.*[^0-9][0-9]{2}$";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your description of what a spam email looks like may be a bit outdated.  But, if you want to exclude such emails in SQL Server, you can -- with a bit of effort.

SQL Server does not support regular expressions, but it does support an enhanced `like`.  So, you can do:

```
where email not like '%.%.%@%' or
      email not like '%[^0-9]%.%.%@$' or
      email not like '%.%[^0-9]%.%@$'
```

This implements three conditions:

- The base email name does not have three parts
- The first part of the base email name has a non-digit
- The second part of the base email name has a non-digit

Combined, these are equivalent to your condition.